# semantic and syntactic performance of Doc2vec model

Tags: python-3.x, word-embedding, doc2vec

I am trying to check the semantic and syntactic performance of a doc2vec model- `doc2vec_model.accuracy(questions-words)`, but it doesnt seem to function since [models.deprecated.doc2vec – Deep learning with paragraph2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/deprecated/doc2vec.html), says it has been deprecated since version 3.3.0 in the gensim package.It gives this error message

```
AttributeError: 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'accuracy'
```

Though it works with word2vec model well, is there any way I can get it done apart from `doc2vec_model.accuracy(questions-words)`? or it's impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

That 'accuracy()' test is *only* a test of word-vectors on analogy problems – an easy evaluation to run, used in a number of papers, but *not* the final authority on whether a set of word-vectors is better than others for a particular purpose. (When I've had a project-specific scoring method, sometimes the word-vectors that score best on project-specific goals don't score best on those analogies – especially if the word-vectors are being used for a classification or information-retrieval task.)

Further, the popular and fast PV-DBOW `Doc2Vec` mode (`dm=0` in gensim) doesn't train word-vectors at all, unless you add another setting (`dbow_words=1`). Such untrained word-vectors will be in random locations, scoring awfully on the analogies-accuracy.

But, using either PV-DM (`dm=1`) mode, or adding `dbow_words=1` to PV-DBOW, will get word-vectors from `Doc2Vec`, and you might still want to run the analogies test. Fortunately, analogy-evaluation options have been retained & even expanded on the `KeyedVectors` object that's held in the `Doc2Vec` `wv` property. You can call the old `accuracy()` method there:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.accuracy

But there's also a slightly-different scoring `evaluate_word_pairs()`:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.evaluate_word_pairs

(And in the 4.0.0 release there'll be a `[evaluate_word_analogies()][1]` which replaces `accuracy().)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I appreciate it